# sphinx search returns no results

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm trying to implement sphinx search for my website however the sphinx api and sphinxse of mariadb return no results. These are my configs:

```
source shops
{
        type                    = mysql
        sql_host                = 127.0.0.1
        sql_user                = user
        sql_pass                = pass
        sql_db                  = shop
        sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
        sql_query               = SELECT id, site,price,  title, content  FROM p2
        sql_attr_uint           = price
        sql_attr_string         = site
        sql_ranged_throttle     = 0
}
index shops
{
    source                  = shops
    path                    = /path/
    morphology              = stem_en
    min_word_len            = 2
    min_prefix_len          = 0
    min_infix_len           = 3
}
```

here is my indexing results:

```
# indexer shops --rotate
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'shops'...
collected 80645 docs, 162.1 MB
sorted 7.8 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 80645 docs, 162088951 bytes
total 8.568 sec, 18916136 bytes/sec, 9411.44 docs/sec
total 80655 reads, 0.045 sec, 0.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 115 writes, 0.069 sec, 499.2 kb/call avg, 0.6 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=19340).
```

My index path contains more than 33 MB of data which seems to be fair and the indexer has done it's job

```
#restart sphinxsearchd 
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
precaching index 'shops'
precached 1 indexes in 0.022 sec
sphinxsearch is restarted.
```

and this is my php file and result:

```
   require_once("sphinxapi.php");
    $s = new SphinxClient;
    $s->setServer("127.0.0.1", 9312); 
    $s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);

    $result = $s->Query($request->getParameter('s'));
     print $s->GetLastError();

    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

and the result:

```
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [warning] => 
    [status] => 0
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => title
            [1] => content
        )

    [attrs] => Array
        (
            [site] => 7
            [price] => 1
        )

    [total] => 0
    [total_found] => 0
    [time] => 0.000
)
```